# Sum up textboxes in excel and insert the value to a cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I want to get the value from textboxes in excel, sum the value and put them into a cell. I want it to happen like a function in a cell. A1 formula - "=b1 + b2", every time i change the value of a textbox, a1 will be different.
I know how to do it the long way, by using a button and when it's pressed I get the value from the textboxes that I need and add them to the specific cell. There will be so much stuff that I'll need to worry about doing it this way, so I want to know if it is possible using a cell function like the above with textboxes.

Comment: If you insert an ActiveX Textbox element on the worksheet you can open it's properties and assign a linked cell. You don't even need to insert a formula. The cell will show the content of the textbox and vise-versa.

Comment: I see you added the C# tag, are you trying to get the textbox value from C# windows forms and put that value into Excel?  If no, see JvDV answer.  If yes, you'll have to use Interop, EPPlus, NPOI, etc libraries to communicate between your program and Excel.

Comment: No, I want to get the value from textboxes in excel, sum the value and put them into a cell. I want it to happen like a function in a cell. A1 formula - "=b1 + b2", every time i change  the value of  b1 or b2, a1 will be different. Sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a text box in the worksheet, then double click on it and put the next code into Click event handler:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

  [a1] = TextBox1.Text

End Sub
```

For the second textbox: `[a2] = TextBox2.Text`

In A3 enter: `=A1+A2`

But why do you need it? The cell itself acts as a textbox, you don't need anything extra.

Comment: I'm going to add an image into the cell itself, and I need to be able to adjust the parameters of the image. the parameters are inconsistent so I can't use columns as I need to fit everything into A4 page

Comment: You can put your data and control on the worksheet anywhere you need. To print out the required area mark it as the print area in the page setup.